# see-through screen to replace foils for checking printed materials?

Tags: displays

I sometimes prepare/print a large number of foils for use in checking printed materials. The foils are overlaid over the printed materials to check that the design is identical. Being able to replace the foils with a transluscent screen (digital display) would be convenient, and perhaps also economical. Does there exist any commercially available products with a transluscent display of A4 size? If not, what is the larges available transluscent display? It could be part of a tablet or require connecting to a PC, as long as it can display PDF files.

Comment: I'm 100% clueless on this topic, but would a projector meet your needs? Or maybe a web camera pointed down on a desk? A web camera attached to an architect light?

Comment: A projector is a good idea, and comparativelyow tech. I like it. +1 for thinking outside the box. Thanks! Additional suggestions still welcome of course!

Comment: Glad you liked the projector idea. For scaling I would use the piece of A4 paper as the screen size and just make sure everything matches. I hope you find the permanent solution, but I'm growing fond of the idea of a mini projector at the end of an architects light... Edit* BTW it's easier to think outside of the box if you have no idea what box your in.